# Compilation error after i upgrade my typescript from 3.4.1 to 3.7.4

Tags: typescript

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Here is the code to reproduce the error:

```
async function f1(): Promise<{a: number}> {
    return Promise.resolve({} as any);
}

async function f2(): Promise<{a: number, b: number}> {
    return Promise.resolve({} as any);
}

(async ()=> {
    const tp = await Promise.all([f1(), f2()]);
    let a = tp[0].a;
    let b = tp[1].a;
    let c = tp[1].b;
    console.log(a, b, c);
})();
```

The error is:

> Error:(13, 19) TS2339: Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a:
>   number; }'.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34925

Comment: @ritaj thanks, i downgrade my typescript to 3.6.4, now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise.All doesn't infer types correctly anymore due to some bug introduced in the later versions, here's a workaround.

```
type PromiseOne = {
    a: number;
}

type PromiseTwo = {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

function f1(): Promise<PromiseOne> {
    return Promise.resolve({ a: 1 });
}

function f2(): Promise<PromiseTwo> {
    return Promise.resolve({ a: 1, b: 2 });
}

(async () => {
    const tp = await Promise.all<PromiseOne, PromiseTwo>([f1(), f2()]);
    let a = tp[0].a;
    let b = tp[1].a;
    let c = tp[1].b;
})();
```

See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34925